# problem on changing a columns' data type in BigQuery

Tags: sql, string, datetime, google-bigquery, type-conversion

I try to change a columns' data type from string to DATETIME (for example '04/12/2016 02:47:30') with the format 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS' but it shoes an error like :
Failed to parse input timestamp string at 8 with format element ' '

The initial file was a csv which i uploaded from my drive. I tried to convert the column's data type from google sheets and then re'upload it, but the column type still remains as string.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you load your CSV file to the `BigQuery` table, you use `autodetect` mode.

Unfortunately with this mode, `BigQuery` will consider your date as `String` even if you changed it from `Google Sheet`.

Instead of using `autodetect`, I propose you using a `Json` schema for your `BigQuery` table.

In your schema you will indicate that the column type for your date field is `timestamp`.

The format you indicated `04/12/2016 02:47:30` is compatible with a timestamp and `BigQuery` will convert it for you.

For the loading file to `BigQuery`, you can directly use the console or `gcloud` cli with [bq](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#bq) command :

```bash
bq load \
    --source_format=CSV \
    mydataset.mytable \
    gs://mybucket/mydata.csv \
    ./myschema.json
```

For the `BigQuery` `Json` schema, the timestamp type is :

```json
{
  {
    "name": "yourDate",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "Your date"
  }
}
```

Comment: I created a Json schema and wrote it in the "Edit as text" option, using either TIMESTAMP or DATETIME for my date column, but unfortunately when running it sends the error "Could not convert value to datetime".                                                                                                                    Nevertheless, thank you for your answer, it was useful knowledge for me!

Comment: You’re welcome :) you need using iso format for dates. You can check from this link for the supported timestamp format : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions?hl=fr